# PHP. Bitcoin to Ukrainian Hrivna price ticker

Tags: php, exchange-server, bitcoin

I am trying to create a real time tiker of the price of bitcoin from the BTC-E.com exchange in Ukrainian currency. The end result is to put the price on my simple html website. 
The exchange does not provide the price in hrivna (UAH), so i have to convert from BTC to USD to UAH. 
So far i have managed to put the price in USD, using the api provided by BTC-E

```
https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker
```

this is the php file i have created

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.

$data = file_get_contents("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$spot_last = $data['ticker']['last'];
echo $spot_last;
?>
```

and this is the code i put in index.html

```
<script>
     var auto_refresh = setInterval(
     function()
     {$('.btce_price').load('ticker.php');}, 1000);


  </script>
```

In order to have USD to UAH conversion i would like to use the commercial rate from one of the banks.

```
 https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=5
```

whis returns the following

```
<exchangerates>
<row>
<exchangerate ccy="RUR" base_ccy="UAH" buy="0.25000" sale="0.28000"/>
</row>
<row>
<exchangerate ccy="EUR" base_ccy="UAH" buy="13.30000" sale="14.30000"/>
</row>
<row>
<exchangerate ccy="USD" base_ccy="UAH" buy="9.60000" sale="10.10000"/>
</row>
</exchangerates>
```

so i have the other php file to output the buy rate that i need

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=5");
$m = $xml->xpath('//exchangerate[@ccy="USD"]');
$exrate = (string)$m[0]['buy'];
echo $exrate;
```

Now back to the question. How divide the output of the first file buy the second? and then display the result in my index.html

Thx!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmm, instead of dividing the values - i would multiply them.

Actually: 1 BTC = 633 USD and 633 USD =~ 6000 UAH.
So i would calculate: $uah = $spot_last * $exrate;

**Example**

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.

// get BTC
$data = file_get_contents("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$spot_last = $data['ticker']['last'];

echo '1 BTC is worth ' . $spot_last . ' USD. <br>';

// get CURRENCIES
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=5");
$m = $xml->xpath('//exchangerate[@ccy="USD"]');
$exrate = (string)$m[0]['buy'];

echo '1 USD is worth '. $exrate .' UAH. <br>';

$uah = $spot_last * $exrate;

echo 'Result: 1 BTC ~ ' . $uah . ' UAH. <br>';
```

For usage as ticker, delete all echos statements, they are just for demonstration and insert just `echo $uah;`

**Output**

```
1 BTC is worth 624.928 USD.
1 USD is worth 9.60000 UAH.
1 BTC ~ 5999.3088 UAH.
```

**Comparison Calc**

see http://preev.com/btc/uah

By the way: it's pretty awesome that Privatbank provides such an API.